# By mistake deleted Android sdk folder and when I try to install new software in eclipse it's showing all are installed

Tags: android, eclipse

By mistake deleted Android sdk folder and when I try to install new software in eclipse using android adt - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ it's showing all items are installed.Its asking to browse sdk folder which I deleted

Comment: your sdk path is missing there. you need to re install the SDK and set the correct path again.

Comment: How to reinstall the sdk?

Comment: C:\Users\[account]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk 

there you can find sdk. and install it.
if it is helped you please upvote the answer.